# Serverless Error: Could not locate deployment bucket. Error: The specified bucket does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm trying to do a simple deployment of a package using Serverless. Yet when I try, I'm getting the error below, saying that my specified bucket doesn't exist.

I've tried this on a per-service basis and it seems like none of my buckets exist, yet I'm looking in S3 and cloudwatch and all the buckets are there.

**Is it possible to get Serverless to output *which* bucket it's trying to access?** I'm finding this error very unhelpful,

```
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  Could not locate deployment bucket. Error: The specified bucket does not exist

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Forums:        forum.serverless.com
     Chat:          gitter.im/serverless/serverless

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     darwin
     Node Version:           6.10.3
     Serverless Version:     1.26.1
```

Comment: I have had this happen when the CloudFormation it creates gets into a bad state somehow -- I would look there.

Answer (score 3):

For anybody else finding this through google, hope this helps. Firstly to answer OP's question

> Is it possible to get Serverless to output which bucket it's trying to access?

Yes. You can find the name of the S3 bucket Serverless is looking for by:

1. Go to your CloudFormation console ie. https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home
2. Pick the correct region from the top right region drop down
3. Select the stack, the stack name is usually the name of your service appended by the stage you were trying to deploy to. You can find the name of your service at the top of your serverless.yml. And the stage is whatever you passed in via -s/--stage; or that you set in your serverless.yml defaulted to '**dev**'.
4. Select the **Resources** tab for the stack
5. Find the row with Logical ID **ServerlessDeploymentBucket**
6. The Physical ID column shows the name of the S3 bucket

If the S3 bucket is missing in the stack, you can always delete the stack and start fresh if that is an option for you. Here's more details about this error - https://seed.run/docs/serverless-errors/the-serverless-deployment-bucket-does-not-exist

Comment: also, check bucket with that name is exists, otherwise create that bucket manually.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin will create your custom deployment bucket if it doesn't exist, and optionally configure the deployment bucket to apply server-side encryption. Make sure, your code build role has s3 related access. follow the below documentation.

https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-deployment-bucket

Answer (score 0):

Serverless deploys to `com.serverless.${self:provider.region}.deploys` by default 
- [documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/). You can give it a custom bucket if you like

It looks like this is your issue [Github Issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4185). There are some answers posted. It might work for you

Answer (score -4):

Yes, you can see the logs. Add `--verbose` to your deploy command. This should do the job.